# Cant get select2 + geonames to work together

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2, geonames

I'm having trouble with using select2 and geonames together. I can generate a list of cities but cant select any as a select option.

HTML

```
<select id="cities" name= "cities">
  <option value="3620194" selected="selected">Choisir une ville</option>
</select>
```

JS

```
function formatRepo (repo) {
      if (repo.loading) return repo.text;

      var markup = "<div class='select2-result-repository clearfix'>" +
        "<div class='select2-result-repository__meta'>" +
            "<div class='select2-result-repository__title'>" + repo.toponymName + "</div>";

      return markup;
    }

    function formatRepoSelection (repo) {
      return repo.toponymName;
    }  

$(document).ready(function() {



    $( '#cities' ).select2({
        ajax: {
            url: "http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON",
            dataType: "json",
            data: function (params) {
                return {
                    username:'xxx',
                    featureClass: "P",
                    style: "full",
                    q: params.term, // search term
                    page: params.page,
                    country: "CH"
                };

            },

            success: function(data) {
                console.log('Success!', data.geonames);
            },
            processResults: function (data, params) {
                // parse the results into the format expected by Select2
                // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
                // alter the remote JSON data, except to indicate that infinite
                // scrolling can be used
                params.page = params.page || 1;

                return {
                    results: data.geonames,
                    pagination: {
                        more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
                    }
                };
            },
        },

        escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, // let our custom formatter work
        minimumInputLength: 1,
        templateResult: formatRepo,
        templateSelection: formatRepoSelection
    });

});
```

You can see the fiddle here: [https://jsfiddle.net/rjvLuof4/][1]

Does anyone know why i can not select a city?

Answer (score 1):

After hours of trial and error i was able to figure this out. Hope it helps anyone.

So basically, Select2 MUST receive an id and text in processResults.

As geonames gives "geonameId" and "toponymName" all you have to do is map them to match  id and text.

Here is the code:

```
processResults: function (data) {

        data = $.map(data.geonames, function (obj) {
            obj.id = obj.id || obj.geonameId;
            obj.text = obj.text || obj.toponymName;
            return obj;
        });
      return {

        results: data,

      };
}
```